# Struggling with Recursion

Tags: ruby, recursion

I've been struggling to learn recursion. This is the solution to finding the sum of the first n numbers. But what if we wanted our first number to be 0? Can anyone help me write a recursive algorithm that sums the first n numbers if the first number starts at 0?

So instead of first_even_numbers_sum(5) being the sum of [2,4,6,8,10].
Its [0,2,4,6,8] and solved recursively.

```
def first_even_numbers_sum(n)
  return 2 if n == 1
  n*2 + first_even_numbers_sum(n-1)
end


first_even_numbers_sum(4)
```

Comment: Adding 0 to a sum of numbers makes no difference.

Comment: you say `Can anyone help me write a recursive algorithm that sums the first n numbers if the first number is 0? ` but you define `first_even_numbers_sum`. What is the actual requirement here? Do you want a recursive sum, or recursive sum combined with some other logic? If you want some other logic, what is the exact requirement?

Comment: I am struggling to understand exactly what result you are looking for, recursive or not. Should the method return the sum from 0 up to `n`? And is being recursive a requirement?

Comment: You need to clarify for your question. If you do not you will receive more downvotes and the question will be closed.

Comment: Alright just clarified.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest the following.

```
def add_em_up(n)
  return 1 if n == 2
  n - 1 + add_em_up(n - 1)
end
```

When writing recursions if it often helpful--even for experienced Rubiests--to add some `puts` statements to see what is going on. Let's do that.

```
def add_em_up(n)
  puts "entered add_em_up(#{ n })"
  puts "returning 1 when n = #{ 2 }" if n == 2
  return 1 if n == 2
  puts "calling add_em_up(#{ n - 1 }) when n = #{ n }"
  t = n - 1 + add_em_up(n - 1)
  puts "returning #{ n } - 1 + #{t - n + 1} = #{t} when n = #{ n }"
  t
end

add_em_up(5)
  #=> 10   
entered add_em_up(5)
calling add_em_up(4) when n = 5
entered add_em_up(4)
calling add_em_up(3) when n = 4
entered add_em_up(3)
calling add_em_up(2) when n = 3
entered add_em_up(2)
returning 1 when n = 2
returning 3 - 1 + 1 = 3 when n = 3
returning 4 - 1 + 3 = 6 when n = 4
returning 5 - 1 + 6 = 10 when n = 5
```

You could use indentation to make things even clearer.

```
INDENT = 3
$col = 0

def add_em_up(n)
  s = " " * $col
  puts "#{ s }entered add_em_up(#{ n })"
  puts "#{ s }returning 1 when n = #{ 2 }" if n == 2
  $col -= INDENT if n == 2
  return 1 if n == 2
  puts "#{ s }calling add_em_up(#{ n - 1 }) when n = #{ n }"
  $col += INDENT
  t = n - 1 + add_em_up(n - 1)
  puts "#{ s }returning #{ n } - 1 + #{t - n + 1} = #{t} when n = #{ n }"
  $col -= INDENT
  t
end

add_em_up(5)
  #=> 10   
entered add_em_up(5)
calling add_em_up(4) when n = 5
   entered add_em_up(4)
   calling add_em_up(3) when n = 4
      entered add_em_up(3)
      calling add_em_up(2) when n = 3
         entered add_em_up(2)
         returning 1 when n = 2
      returning 3 - 1 + 1 = 3 when n = 3
   returning 4 - 1 + 3 = 6 when n = 4
returning 5 - 1 + 6 = 10 when n = 5
```

Note that in the first version of this method (no indentation) one could replace

```
t = n - 1 + add_em_up(n - 1)
puts "returning #{ n } - 1 + #{t - n + 1} = #{t} when n = #{ n }"
t
```

with

```
(n - 1 + add_em_up(n - 1)).
  tap { |t| puts "returning #{ n } - 1 + #{t - n + 1} = #{t} when n = #{ n }" }
```

or (as pointed out in a comment)

```
(n - 1 + add_em_up(n - 1)).yield_self { |t| 
  puts "returning #{ n } - 1 + #{t - n + 1} = #{t} when n = #{ n }"; t }
```

Here and more generally, the method [Object#tap](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Object.html#method-i-tap) is very useful for debugging. [Object#yield_self](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Object.html#method-i-yield_self) (new in Ruby v2.5) is another useful method.

Comment: Can we not print the return of `yield_self` instead of what you have with `tap`?

Comment: @Sagar, thanks for the suggestion. I did an edit to add it. I recall you mentioning `yield_self` in a comment a couple of weeks ago. I had not heard of it previously and intended to investigate it but have not done so until now.